# TinyMCE removes Bootstrap glyphicons etc. How to keep them intact?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tinymce, tinymce-4

I use TinyMCE (v4) in my CMS, and I have made it easy to add pre-made HTML into the editor. This works wonderful.

But TinyMCE removes empty div, span etc unless it is specified in TinyMCE config to keep them.

This works well, except when there is an "empty" element inside another empty element. Like this: (typical Bootstrap icon use)

```
<div class="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
```

In the TinyMCE config I have tried:

```
extended_valid_elements : "div[class|id|style|span],span[class|id|style]",
```

and

```
extended_valid_elements : "div[* ],span[* ]",
```

but they always delete the **inner** span, so it looks like this:

```
<div class="icon"></div>
```

HOWEVER, If I write like this:

```
<div class="icon"></div> <span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
```

both are kept.

***So the case is this:***  if I have an empty span inside an empty div (or any other empty element with a css class inside another empty element with a css class), it deletes the element that is inside the other.

How can I set a config in TinyMCE that allows me to write (and keep) this:

```
<div class="icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></div>
```

Comment: Why not use `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>`?

Comment: @Aibrean It's because I use some ready made bootstrap designs, and they have used '<div class="icon>"' and similar as a wrapper to customize the designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was made by Spocke, the original owner of Tiny MCE. He added in 4.1.1 (released yesterday) a function that allows the above.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround it works if you add a space after the glyphicon in the WP editor.